# how to connect to hdmi TV by non hdmi mobile?

Tags: hdmi

I want to know how to connect my in focus m810 with HDMI tv. Note my TV doesn't have WiFi, so wireless display can't be used.

Comment: ChromeCast is the way to go. Your phone does not support slimport or any  other standards for hdmi over MicroUSB.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered many times before... usually by me.

I personally use [Amazon Fire TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3FPN4U) and the [Amazon Fire Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GDQ0RMG) and it works well connected with my Galaxy S3 and Galaxy Tab 4. The [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-display-adapter) is supposed to work with Android devices as well.

How to use display mirroring on the Fire TV and Stick (from Amazon's website):

> To quickly start display mirroring, on your Amazon Fire TV remote
>   press and hold the Home button and select Mirroring. Then connect your
>   compatible device. Swipe down from the top of the screen to open Quick
>   Settings, and then tap Settings. Tap Display & Sounds, and then tap
>   Display Mirroring.

Also note that Chromecast doesn't stream everything from the device. It streams from the Chrome browser and select apps. Miracast enabled devices, like the Fire Stick, stream any video and audio that is on the mobile device screen (with a slight delay, of course).

Hope this helps!